# Unable to see the input option in my SoapUI testcases !! Using version 5.2.1

Tags: soapui

I want to generate some Testcases mapping with the operations generated in SoapUI after adding a WSDL file.
Steps:

1. Added a WSDL file http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx in SoapUI.
2. SoapUI generated the operations in it automatically.
3. Check the following Soap XML request I want to use for generating Testcase below:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:getAirportInformationByISOCountryCode>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <web:CountryAbbrviation>?</web:CountryAbbrviation>
    </web:getAirportInformationByISOCountryCode>
</soapenv:Body>
```

4. Now I create a Testsuite, added a Testcase and while adding a Soap Request teststep, I mapped with the above operation.
5. Now check the Soap request below which SoapUI generated after mapping with operation

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <web:getAirportInformationByISOCountryCode/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

6. You can see there is no input option in this above Soap Request as the tag     `<web:CountryAbbrviation>?</web:CountryAbbrviation>` is missing under tag      `<web:getAirportInformationByISOCountryCode/>`

Please let me know is there any setting in SoapUI I am missing while generating a Soap Request test step after mapping with an operation. Currently I am just adding the missing input tag manually but I am sure it is not the right practice.

Comment: Re-try it, Recreate everything ; it should have worked.

Comment: Did you pass any data instead of just `?` in the request?

Comment: Yes I have passed some data in the input option, is this the reason?

Comment: I have tried everything, recreated everything from the beginning, didn't passed any data in the default operations in place of "?", but still not getting any input options in this teststeps.

Comment: What is your setting for "Include Optional" in WSDL preferences? See: https://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/reference/preferences-and-settings.html

Comment: My WSDL setting is Cache WSDLs, Include Optional, Pretty Print and Name with Binding checkbox are selected. Excluded types "schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". I haven't changed any WSDL setting after installing, it is set what is default.